# theme injecting css into wp-admin

Tags: wp-admin, css, admin-css

Some of the CSS from my theme is being used in wp-admin.

For instance "Add New Page" on `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page` is coloured blue, which comes from my theme, as stated by Chrome code inspector.

[image]

This is my theme's functions.php:

```
<?php

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
    $content_width = 940;

function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('primary',__( 'Primary Menu' ));
  register_nav_menu('footer',__( 'Footer Menu' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );


function simple_rabbit_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'simple-rabbit' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-0',
        'description' => __( 'Appears on all pages', 'simple-rabbit' ), 
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Footer Widget Area', 'simple-rabbit' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Appears on all pages', 'simple-rabbit' ), 
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'simple_rabbit_widgets_init' );

wp_register_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri());
wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri());

/* 
 * Loads the Options Panel
 *
 * If you're loading from a child theme use stylesheet_directory
 * instead of template_directory
 */

if ( !function_exists( 'optionsframework_init' ) ) {
    define( 'OPTIONS_FRAMEWORK_DIRECTORY', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/' );
    require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/inc/options-framework.php';
}

/* 
 * This is an example of how to add custom scripts to the options panel.
 * This one shows/hides the an option when a checkbox is clicked.
 *
 * You can delete it if you not using that option
 */

add_action('optionsframework_custom_scripts', 'optionsframework_custom_scripts');



function twentytwelve_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    switch ( $comment->comment_type ) :
        case 'pingback' :
        case 'trackback' :
        // Display trackbacks differently than normal comments.
    ?>

<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
  <p>
    <?php _e( 'Pingback:', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
    <?php comment_author_link(); ?>
    <?php edit_comment_link( __( '(Edit)', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
  </p>
  <?php
    break;
    default :
    // Proceed with normal comments.
    global $post;
  ?>
<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="li-comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
  <article id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" class="comment">
    <header class="comment-meta comment-author vcard">
      <?php
        echo get_avatar( $comment, 44 );
        printf( '<cite class="fn">%1$s %2$s</cite>',
        get_comment_author_link(),
        // If current post author is also comment author, make it known visually.
            ( $comment->user_id === $post->post_author ) ? '<span> ' . __( 'Post author', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>' : '');
                printf( '<a href="%1$s"><time datetime="%2$s">%3$s</time></a>',
                esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ),
                get_comment_time( 'c' ),
                /* translators: 1: date, 2: time */
                sprintf( __( '%1$s at %2$s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_comment_date(), get_comment_time() )
                );
        ?>
    </header>
    <!-- .comment-meta -->

    <?php if ( '0' == $comment->comment_approved ) : ?>
    <p class="comment-awaiting-moderation">
      <?php _e( 'Your comment is awaiting moderation.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <section class="comment-content comment">
      <?php comment_text(); ?>
      <?php edit_comment_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<p class="edit-link">', '</p>' ); ?>
    </section>
    <!-- .comment-content -->

    <div class="reply">
      <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'reply_text' => __( 'Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => ' <span>&darr;</span>', 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
    </div>
    <!-- .reply --> 

  </article>
  <!-- #comment-## -->

  <?php
    break;
    endswitch; // end comment_type check
}

function optionsframework_custom_scripts() { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#example_showhidden').click(function() {
        jQuery('#section-example_text_hidden').fadeToggle(400);
    });

    if (jQuery('#example_showhidden:checked').val() !== undefined) {
        jQuery('#section-example_text_hidden').show();
    }

});
</script>
  <?php
}

function simple_rabbit_scripts_styles() {

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'simple_rabbit_scripts_styles' );

add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );
```

Can you help me determine how the CSS is being injected? Thank you.

Comment: Enable the [debug mode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and you get the solution for free. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are enqueue the CSS file of your theme outside any of the recommended actions. If you want it to be added only in frontend, you should use [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_register_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mainstyle', get_stylesheet_uri());
});
```